# Cannot debug C/C++ code using eclipse as debug information is missing

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, debug-mode

I am trying to debug a **C** project in mint Linux using *eclipse Galileo IDE*. 
When I try to run the project in the *DEBUG* mode, the process terminates as it says-     debugging information is missing.

In the eclipse console following messages appear

```
No source available for "main() " 

and 

Reading symbols from /home/project/netconf/target/bin/netconfd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I am using the custom build command

> make DEBUG=1 STATIC=1    [eclipse >project >properties > c/c++ build > builder settings]

it builds and runs fine in *RELEASE* mode.

I am able to build the same application using normal command line build using command terminal, using the same build options

```
> sudo make DEBUG=1 STATIC=1
```

now I can start a command line *gdb session*, as the debugging info is generated, but it is very difficult to debug that way.

---

I need to know if there is any other setting that needs to be changed, so that I can start debugging in eclipse.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: I am getting a message "No source available for "main() " and in the console Reading symbols from /home/project/netconf/target/bin/netconfd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Comment: Is it CMake based project? I've noticed such behavior for CMake generated projects with default settings. I had to explicitly set CMAKE_DEBUG_TYPE to Debug before configuring and generating a project with cmake-gui. After that everything is fine in Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 1):

Add -d (or probably -g) to your command line. I think DEBUG=1 is defining a macro rather than generating debug info

Comment: -g more likely, with maybe -DDEBUG

Comment: I have tried with both -g and -d , but still the debug info is not generated.